# How can I load a page with checkboxes checked according to database info

Tags: sql, asp.net-mvc, razor

I know there is a few post about it. I've tryed to work with the answer but I must be missing something somewhere (I'm pretty noob).

As I said in the title, I would like to have a page that show a big list of item checked or not according to database information. The page load with an Id.
Type: CSHTML, Razor
Database: defect
Table name: defectqc

The table is looking a bit like that so far:

```
    <table>     
    <tr><td><p><input type="checkbox" name="ltcheck1" checked="@ltcheck1"></td></tr>
    <tr><td><p><input type="checkbox" name="ltcheck2" checked="@ltcheck2"></td></tr>
    <tr><td><p><input type="checkbox" name="ltcheck3" checked="@ltcheck3"></td> </tr>
    </table>
```

So the code script I've tryed at the begining is this one...

```
    var Id = "";
    var ltcheck1 = "";
    var ltcheck2 = "";
    var ltcheck3 = "";

   if(!IsPost){
    if(!Request.QueryString["Id"].IsEmpty() && Request.QueryString["Id"].IsInt()) {
        Id = Request.QueryString["Id"];
        var db = Database.Open("defect");
        var dbCommand = "SELECT * FROM defectqc WHERE Id = @0";
        var row = db.QuerySingle(dbCommand, Id);
   if(row != null) {
     ltcheck1 = row.ltcheck1;
     ltcheck2 = row.ltcheck2;
     ltcheck2 = row.ltcheck3;
 }
```

The database got column written "True" or "False" into it. I want the checkboxes to be checked if the column is "true"

Please MTV! Pimp my ride! ;D

Sorry for my english, I'm trying hard

Comment: If you're using MVC, you should be creating a Model and passing it to the View. Then you use                             `@Html.CheckBoxFor(model => model.ltcheck)` which will create a checkbox - checked if `ltcheck` is true

Comment: I've read something about that. But I don't understand how it works

Comment: I recommend trying to find out how it works, otherwise it's almost pointless using MVC! There must be hundreds of MVC tutorials online, or buy a book - that's how I learned.

Comment: I got a very strict table... How would I tell the page to put the checkboxe into the right section?

Comment: You would still use HTML markup to dictate where the value was displayed, e.g.<td>@Html.CheckBoxFor(model => model.ltcheck)</td>

Comment: And how would I tell to the system that this checkbox is related to this variable? Do I need to make a model for each checkboxe? (Thank you for the help it's very appreciated and sorry for the slow learning)

Comment: You're creating a checkbox based on the model property `ltcheck`, so when the form is posted, the property is bound to model.ltcheck. The model would contain bool properties representing the checkbox values.  To be honest, you should spend some time reading about the subject to get an understanding of the basics, _then_ ask the questions here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Following your logic Schaemelhout Would it be possible if I use this kind of statement

```
var Id = "";
var ltcheck1 = "";
var ltcheck2 = "";
var ltcheck3 = "";

if(!IsPost){
if(!Request.QueryString["Id"].IsEmpty() && Request.QueryString["Id"].IsInt()) {
    Id = Request.QueryString["Id"];
    var db = Database.Open("defect");
    var dbCommand = "SELECT * FROM defectqc WHERE Id = @0";
    var row = db.QuerySingle(dbCommand, Id);


if(row.ltcheck1 = "true") {
      ltcheck1.checked
 }
if(row.ltcheck2 = "true") {
      ltcheck1.checked
 }
```

(I know the syntax isn't correct)

I found this which is in PHP

```
  <input type="checkbox" name="ltcheck1" value="True" <?php echo $checked; ?> />
  if ($row['letcheck1'] == 'True') $checked = 'checked="checked"';
```

Assuming that the data have already been pulled out. It would do exactly what I need... Is there a way to translate it?

Answer (score 0):

```
<input type="checkbox"/>
```

Will only be checked if you use the attribute

```
checked
```

or

```
checked="checked"
```

So try to generate this:

```
<input type="checkbox" checked/>
```

Comment: You mean with a kind of "if" statement?

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you use the html helpers?

```
@Html.CheckBox("ltcheck1")
@Html.CheckBox("ltcheck2")
@Html.CheckBox("ltcheck3")
```

Comment: arg! I hate you all... Ok ok I'll try to learn how it works =). It seems to be the only way

Comment: Can you give me an exemple how you would take the information of the database and make the checkbox checked according to it?